# Libwebrtc and cmake

Tags: cmake, webrtc

I got WebRTC native package by following this https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/ and depot_tools at C:\depot_tools location. Then wanted to try this https://github.com/aisouard/libwebrtc to make development process easier but while following steps for windows at `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"` step i get error

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindPackageHandle
StandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Git (missing: GIT_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.
cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindGit.cmake:83 (find_package
_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is unclear in the error message `Could NOT find Git`? You need to have `Git` installed for being able to build your project.

Comment: The thing is i have installed git already but its in c:\depot_tools and it looks like it cannot find it but i have no idea how to tell him to search in this specific folder for it

Comment: So the question shouldn't sound like "I got unknown error in CMake, what to do?", but "How to help CMake to find GIT?", or, at least, "Why CMake cannot find GIT while it is installed?", should it?